# Need to load video in CStatic control

Tags: c++, mfc, video-streaming

I need load a video of any file format into a CStatic control for my MFC application I have written the code as I studied from web to load it. The Code snippet is given below. But it doesn't work. Any idea about it?

```
LRESULT SIMTankConfigureWindowDlg::OnFinishedFrame(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if(m_bFinishIntroMovie)
    {

        m_pGraph->play();
    }   
    else
    {   
        //
        //SAFE_DELETE(m_pGraph);
        m_bFinishIntroMovie = true;
        m_staticMovieCanvas.ShowWindow(0);
        m_staticMovieCanvas.MoveWindow(310,52, 345, 167);       
        m_pGraph->setSizeDisplayWindow(CSize(345, 167));

        //
        CString str;
        str = m_strCurrentDirName + "\\" + _T("T-59Tank.mpg");
        LPWSTR lpszW = new WCHAR[255];
        LPTSTR lpStr = str.GetBuffer( str.GetLength() );
        int nLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0,lpStr, -1, NULL, NULL);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpStr, -1, lpszW, nLen);     

        //
        hr = m_pGraph->openFile(lpszW, 0);
        if(SUCCEEDED(m_pGraph->play()))
        {   
            //
            m_staticMovieCanvas.ShowWindow(1);  
        }

        delete[] lpszW;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't provided enough information about the rest of your program to make a solid assessment. Including a link to the example you have based your code on would help.

Comment: Thank u Chet.   >>"Including a link to the example you have based your code on would help."  Did you mean that I should upload all the codes of my programm?

Comment: What's the type of 'm_pGraph' and how are you initializing it? Is it child of static-control?